Automapper configuration to map base dictionary values and members as normal
I have the following classes.
public class FieldValue
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class FieldValues
{
    public FieldValue[] Values { get; set; }
}

public static class FieldValuesExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this FieldValues self)
    {
        return self.Values.ToDictionary(v => v.Field, v => v.Value);
    }
}

public class SourceClass : FieldValues
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationClassB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

SourceClass derives from FieldValues and has its own fields. DestinationClassX types are composed of fields only.
I need to map from SourceClass to DestinationClassX as follows:
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test(IMapper mapper)
    {
        // create a SourceClass object
        SourceClass source = new() {
            Id = 123,
            Name = "Foo",
            Values = new FieldValue[] {
                new() { Field = "Field1", Value = "Value1" },
                new() { Field = "Field2", Value = "Value2" },
                new() { Field = "Field3", Value = "Value3" },
                new() { Field = "Field4", Value = "Value4" }
            }
        };

        // how do we setup mapping configuration to achieve the following?

        // map to DestinationClassA
        DestinationClassA destinationA = mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationAClass>(source);
        // destinationA.Id == 123;
        // destinationA.Field1 == "Value1";
        // destinationA.Field2 == "Value2";

        // map to DestinationClassB
        DestinationClassB destinationB = mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationBClass>(source);
        // destinationB.Name == "Foo";
        // destinationB.Field2 == "Value2";
        // destinationB.Field3 == "Value3";
    }
}

I need to set up Automapper mapping to map from SourceClass to DestinationClassX so that any matching destination fields are mapped from:

any matching Field/Value from SourceClass's base FieldValues

as well as any matching members from SourceClass itself as normal.


I understand that Automapper can automatically map from dynamic objects as well as IDictionary<string, object>. If I have, for example a class with a DestinationClassX member:
public class DestinationClassWithA
{
    public DestinationClassA A { get; set; }
}

with the following mapping:
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassA>(); // map 1

CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassWithA>() 
    .ForMember(dst => dst.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ToDictionary())); // map 2

Destination.A Field1 and Field2 are populated as per map 2, but Id from map 1 is set to null. If I comment out map 2, map 1 works but of course I don't get the dictionary entries.
I'm not sure how to incorporate the dictionary map (map 2) into map 1.
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassA>()
    // what goes here? 

CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassB>()
    // what goes here? 


This question is similar to: Dictionary <string,string> map to an object using Automapper. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Progman similar, but didn't quite solve the issue as I don't map from just a IDictionary.

You need to make the mapping in two steps. AfterMap helps with that. And you can also use mapping inheritance to reuse the configuration in the derived maps.
cfg.CreateMap<FieldValues, object>().AfterMap((s,d,c)=>c.Mapper.Map(s.ToDictionary(), d));
cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassA>(MemberList.None).IncludeBase<FieldValues, object>();
cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClassB>(MemberList.None).IncludeBase<FieldValues, object>();


@Petrock This seems to answer your question.
